# How do I start and restart an application in Tomcat 9?

Tags: tomcat

I want the folder "mytestapp" to be created in the "webapps" folder in Tomcat.

"mytestapp.war" with the application that he would take from the "myapp_1" folder, which is the same in the "webapps" folder, and placed in the "mytestapp" folder.

And the "application.properties" for the application were taken from the "myapp_1" folder.

When adding a new "mytestapp.war" to the folder "myapp_1" - the content was overwritten - the application was restarted.

```
<Host name="mytestapp" appBase="webapps" autoDeploy="true">
    <Context path="/mytestapp" docBase="c:/Apache-tomcat/webapps/myapp_1/mytestapp.war" debug="0" reloadable="true">
        <Environment name="spring.config.location" value="file:c:/Apache-tomcat/webapps/myapp_1/application.properties" type="java.lang.String"/>
    </Context>
</Host>
```

I add the code above to "server.xml".
it only fires once - if there is no "mytestapp" folder.
He does everything as I plan.
But if he has already done it once, then he does nothing more.

Comment: 1. All folders inside `webapps` are deployed as applications. You shouldn't put folders as `myapp_1` (which I assume contains the source code) in that folder. 2. `<Context>`s in `server.xml` are not checked for changes, you should put the element in `conf/Catalina/localhost/mytestapp.xml`.

Comment: created a folder "c: / Apache-tomcat / myapp_1 /" for my application.

in "server.xml" added only this -
<Host name = "mytestapp" appBase = "webapps" autoDeploy = "true"> </Host>

created a file "c: /Apache-tomcat/conf/Catalina/localhost/mytestapp.xml" with the content -
    <Context path = "/ mytestapp" docBase = "c: /Apache-tomcat/myapp_1/mytestapp.war" debug = "0" reloadable = "true">
        <Environment name = "spring.config.location" value = "file: c: /Apache-tomcat/myapp_1/application.properties" type = "java.lang.String" />
    </Context>

Comment: everything works as I wanted, but there is "WARNING" in the logs -
WARNING [Catalina-utility-2] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor The path attribute with value [/ mytestapp] in deployment descriptor [C: \ Apache-tomcat \ conf \ Catalina \ localhost \ mytestapp.xml] has been ignored
WARNING [Catalina-utility-2] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor A docBase [C: \ Apache-tomcat \ webapps] inside the host appBase has been specified, and will be ignored

Comment: WARNING [Catalina-utility-2] org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule.begin Match [Context] failed to set property [debug] to [0]
what needs to be fixed?

Comment: Check [Tomcat's documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/context.html#Naming): there is no `debug` attribute on the context element. Also the `path` attribute is ignored for files in `conf/Catalina/localhost`: the context path is determined by the name of the file.